# workflow settings: user cannot be found

Tags: workflow, error

I have created a calendar.  when I go to the calendar settings page and click on Workflow Settings I get an error message that says: Error: User cannot be found

I have not created any workflows yet for this calendar.  I've seen many resolutions to this error that involve republishing an existing workflow, but in this case there is no existing workflow.

I've also attempted to deactive and reactivate the site collection feature called Workflows.  Again, this does not resolve my issue.

any other recommendations?

Answer (score 1):

It means that the user column is set to "Nil" in the workflow. This can be solved easily.

1. Open the SharePoint website in SharePoint Designer
2. Click "All Files" in the Navigation (Now all the files and folders will be displayed)
3. Go into `_catalogs` folder
4. Go into "wfpub" folder (here you can see all the workflows in their respected folders)
5. Go into the workflow's folder that you want to use
6. Edit the file (your-workflow-name).xoml.wfconfig.xml
7. Find `<d:Assignee/>` and `<d:CC/>` (probably they are line 119 and 129)
8. If `<d:Assignee/>` looks as `<d:Assignee xsi:nil="true"/>` then take out that `xsi:nil="true"`. Do the same for `<d:CC/>`
9. Save the file. Now it will work.

Answer (score 0):

In order to fix this issue, I needed to use SP Designer to republish all workflows in the Site Collection and the site.